# Angular - Compare strings

Tags: angular

The problem is simple:

I need compare current user with list of users

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
     <td>
     <a *ngIf="'user.usuario' != usuario" title="{{'delete' | translate}}" 
          (click)="delete(user)"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a> 
     </td>
</tr>
```

Current user is **usuario** and **user.usuario** is a users for loop. When *user.usuario!=usuario* i need to show this element, when is *user.usuario==usuario* i need to hide it.

The problem: This condition doesn´t works. What´s is wrong? **{{usuario}}** return value.

**UPDATE**

**Array of users**

```
0: {idUsuario: 20, usuario: "iotadmin", nombre: null, apellidos: null, …}
1: {idUsuario: 21, usuario: "xiborra", nombre: "Xavi", apellidos: "Iborra", …}
2: {idUsuario: 22, usuario: "sergio", nombre: "Sergio", apellidos: "Hernando", …}
3: {idUsuario: 23, usuario: "alara", nombre: "Asier", apellidos: "Lara", …}
4: {idUsuario: 25, usuario: "jmanrique", nombre: "Jorge", apellidos: "Manrique", …}
5: {idUsuario: 26, usuario: "jaltamira", nombre: "Jorge", apellidos: "Altamira", …}
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**User**

console.log(this.usuario)

```
alara
```

In HTML {{usuario}} return

```
[OBJECT][OBJECT]
```

Comment: can you share how `users` and `usuario` looks like..

Comment: Is `usuario` getting replaced somewhere in your code?  As in console you displayed a string and in HTML, an object. `console.log(typeof(this.usuario));` and show

Comment: console.log(typeof(this.usuario)) return string. Maybe for loop change something?

Comment: change `{{usario}}` to `{{usario | json}}` please

Comment: Return "alara" in HTML. Show the question now is.. how can if do condition? I try user.usuario != usuario | json and doesn´t work. .

Comment: use `user.usuario` without `'` in your conditional

Comment: <a *ngIf="user.usuario != {{usuario |json}}" title="{{'delete' | translate}}"
                    (click)="delete(user)"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>  no work

Comment: It doesnt work because of incorrect syntax. `{{ }}` is used for interpolation. Have a look here https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Answer (score 5):

Replace `'user.usuario'` with `user.usuario`, don't add the quote.

Try this:

```
<a *ngIf="user.usuario != usuario" title="{{'delete' | translate}}" 
              (click)="delete(user)"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
```

Comment: It should! Can you share it in stackBiltz

Comment: Else just interpolate {{user.usuario}} and {{usuario}} just above your anchor tag ans check if both the string matches. (Debugging purpose)

Comment: I think it is better to compare with triple equals (===) as it compares both equality and being of same type.

Comment: It's possible `usuario` is an object (example: `{a: {x:'b'}} != {a: {x:'b'}}` -> `true`)

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre, Can u show {{usuario | json}}, or just console.log(usuario) and show the result

Comment: Correct. Don´t know why but is a object. I try user.usuario != usuario | json" but don´t work.

Comment: Then your `usuario` should have some unique identifier so you can compare `...*ngIf="user.usuario.id != usuario.id"...`

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre Can you show `users` and `usuario`, i will modify the answer based on that

Answer (score 0):

I have run and verified this sample in https://stackblitz.com

Please follow below thread -

In component i have added a static array named "users"

```
export class AppComponent  {    
users=[{"usuario":"iotadmin","idUsuario":1},
{"usuario":"xiborra","idUsuario":2},
{"usuario":"sergio","idUsuario":3},
{"usuario":"alara","idUsuario":4},
{"usuario":"jmanrique","idUsuario":5},
{"usuario":"jaltamira","idUsuario":5}];
currentUser='iotadmin';
}
```

and in HTML -

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
 <td>      
 <a *ngIf="user.usuario != currentUser" title="{{'delete'}}" 
      (click)="delete(user)">{{user.usuario}} <i class="fa fa-trash">delete</i></a> 
 </td>
</tr>
```

The output will be displayed as -

```
xiborra delete  
sergio delete   
alara delete
jmanrique delete
jaltamira delete
```

it hides user "iotadmin" which is the current user.

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

Use triple equals `(===)` for comparing and add a method which convert **`usuario`** to string value.

```
 <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
         <td>
         <a *ngIf="user.usuario !== getUserio()" title="{{'delete' | translate}}" 
              (click)="delete(user)"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a> 
         </td>
    </tr>
```

**In Component :**

```
 getUserio() {
    return JSON.stringify(this.usuario);
 }
```

I know it's costly to call a method from directive but this looks possible way to solve this issue. :)

Comment: Returnn ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: can you try with JSON.parse().. ?